# Wortsuche: Kontakt ohne reale Treffen

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche ein Wort, mit dem ich ausdrücken kann, dass ich mit einer Person nur über E-Mail, SMS, Messager, Social Media, Chat, Skype, Brief oder telefonisch Kontakt habe (alles, außer direktem physischen Kontakt).

Online-Kommunikation war mein erster Einfall, aber das Telefonieren passt da meiner Meinung nach nicht rein. Auch Wortkombinationen mit "Fern" passen nicht so richtig, weil die Art der Kommunikation nicht mit der Entfernung zusammen hängt, ich könnte ja trotzdem mit der Person in derselben Straße wohnen.

*Der Kontext für die Wortsuche:*

*Ein Freund wurde [geghostet](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosting_(Beziehungsproblem)) und hat sich beklagt über wie viele Kanäle er schon versucht hat Kontakt aufzunehmen, immer ohne Erfolg. Auf die Idee zu kommen bei ihr vorbei zu gehen und zu klingeln oder einen Ort zu besuchen, wo sie regelmäßig ist um sie dort anzusprechen, kam er aber nicht, obwohl sie sich schon real getroffen hatten. Ich meinte daher zu ihm, dass das Problem bei Ghosting die ??? Kommunikation sei.*

Comment: "Fern" passt an sich schon - Ein Fernseher ist und bleibt ein Fernseher, auch wenn er direkt im Sender neben der Kamera steht .

Comment: Was ist denn "ghosten"?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Von "Ghosting" spricht man, wenn jemand plötzlich und ohne Vorwarnung nicht mehr auf Kontaktversuche reagiert. Stell' Dir beispielsweise vor, Du schreibst mit jemandem regelmäßig Mails. Von einem Tag auf den anderen antwortet diese Person nicht mehr auf Deine Mails, geht nicht ans Telefon wenn Du anrufst, reagiert nicht auf Nachrichten in Messengern die Ihr sonst benutzt habt usw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Du suchst den Begriff **mediale Kommunikation**.

Eine Alternative wäre noch vermittelte Kommunikation oder technisch vermittelte Kommunikation.

Comment: Nicht jede mediale Kommunikation ist Fernkommunikation, z. B. wenn Pilot und Kopilot über Headset kommunizieren, obwohl sie nebeneinander sitzen.

Comment: Dass es aus der Ferne sein muss war gar nicht die Anforderung, sondern im Gegenteil: Es wurde ausdrücklich darauf hingewiesen, dass Ferne kein Kriterium ist.

Comment: Das in der Frage stehende _»alles außer ph«_ interpretiere ich als _»alles außer physischen Kontakt«_, was bei nebeneinander befindlichen Personen aber der Fall wäre. Auch bei _hintereinander_ befindlichen wie zwei Motorradfahrern mit Helmsprechanlage. Und Ferne wurde nur mit dem Argument _»in der gleichen Straße wohnen«_ abgelehnt. Wenn ich den Nachbarn von gegenüber anrufe, ist das für mich jedoch Telekommunikation.

Comment: Nun, dass der Ausdruck vielleicht für exotische, konstruierte Randfälle nicht passt, würde ich sofort akzeptieren, wenn es einen üblichen und handlichen Begriff gäbe, der besser passt. Das sehe ich aber nicht gegeben. Spitzfindig kann ich auch sagen, dass ein Telefonanruf in eine Wohnung 2 Häuser weiter dann keine Telekommunikation ist, wenn ich zwar anrufe, aber nichts sage.

Comment: Ist gesprochene Sprache von Angesicht zu Angesicht kein Medium? Beim Ausdruck »mediale Kommunikation« müsste ich erstmal überlegen: Medien im Sinne von Schriftmedien wie Zeitung? Nein, ergibt keinen Sinn. Also allgemeiner, und dazu zählt auch *face-to-face*.

Comment: @Philipp: Die Sprache ist durchaus ein Medium, aber wird im direkten Gespräch eben nicht über ein weiteres Medium übertragen, außer über die Luft, die aber üblicherweise schon da ist. Bei all den anderen Kommunikationen ist Sprache ja auch in Gebrauch, aber die Sprache wird über ein weiteres Medium übertragen.

Answer (score 3):

Hier funktioniert wahrscheinlich Ausschluss einfacher als Einschluss - Einen Begriff für "alles außer Face-to-Face" scheint es nicht zu geben.

- "indirekt" könnte passen, meint aber eher "Kommunikation über Dritte"
- "unpersönlich" könnte als das Gegenteil zu "von Angesicht zu Angesicht", also "persönlich", funktionieren, ist aber leider schon (sehr negativ) durch eine andere Bedeutung belegt.
- "elektronisch" passt auch ein bißchen, fasst aber z.B. den Brief nicht
- "schriftlich und fernmündlich" ist ziemlich altmodisch und umfasst nicht automatisch Soziale Medien

Die Amis würden wahrscheinlich "non-face-to-face" sagen, "nicht von Angesicht zu Angesicht" ist aber ziemlich geschraubt. Ich würde einen Satz draus machen, der genau sagt, was du meinst, wie z.B.

- > ... da wir uns bisher noch nicht persönlich getroffen haben ...
- > ... weil wir uns bisher noch nicht direkt gesprochen haben ...
- > ... wenn man sich noch nie direkt gegenüber stand ...

Answer (score 2):

Kontakte zwischen räumlich getrennten Personen würde ich

> Telekommunikation

nennen.

Comment: Ist eine Postkarte auch "Telekommunikation"?

Comment: @tofro: Die Postkarte selbst nicht.

Comment: Kommunikation per Brief und Postkarte soll aber explizit eingeschlossen sein.

Comment: @tofro: Mit meinem ersten Kommentar wollte ich sagen, dass ich das für Telekommunikation halte.

Comment: Ich schlage vor zu formulieren: "Synchrone Kontakte zwischen...", denn die Postkarte ist eine Form asynchroner Kommunikation.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Und was ist dann mit der Kommunikation mit einem Marsianer? Aufgrund der spürbaren Zeitverzögerung könnte man das kaum synchron nennen.

Comment: @Pollitzer  Ich schlage vor, dies zu erörtern, sobald der Fall konkret eintritt. Die Frage an sich ist natürlich interessant. Interessant wäre aber auch die Frage, ob eine Postkarte als synchrone Kommunikation gelten kann, wenn man zu Ihrer Versendung eine vordatierende Zeitmaschine verwendet.

Answer (score 1):

Nach Lektüre der verschiedenen (ganz guten) Antworten hier komme ich für mich zu dem Schluss, dass es eine One-fits-all-Lösung hier nicht gibt. Je nach Kontext wird man unterschiedliche Ausdrucksformen wählen.

Im Beispiel, das der Frage beigegeben war, würde ich aber folgende Lösung(en) sehen:

(Beispiel-Text hier mit korrigierter Orthographie, Syntax und insbesondere Zeichensetzung)

> Ein Freund wurde geghostet und hat sich beklagt, über wie viele Kanäle er schon versucht hat, Kontakt aufzunehmen, immer ohne Erfolg. Auf die Idee, bei ihr vorbeizugehen und zu klingeln oder einen Ort aufzusuchen, wo sie regelmäßig ist, um sie dort anzusprechen, kam er aber nicht, obwohl sie sich schon real getroffen hatten. Ich sagte ihm daher, dass das Problem bei diesem Ghosting...

Nun verschiedene Lösungen:

> ... die Kommunikation sei: Briefe, E-Mails und so weiter kann man übersehen. Er solle sie doch einmal persönlich ansprechen.
>
> ... das Fehlen des unmittelbaren Kontakt sei.
>
> ... die mediale Vermittlung des Kontakts sei. Er solle sie doch einfach persönlich ansprechen.
>
> ... die Kommunikation auf Distanz sei. Wenn er sie von Angesicht zu Angesicht anspräche, würde sie wohl reagieren.

Answer (score 1):

Neben der medialen (=vermittelten) Kommunikation (bzw. Kontakt) kann man auch von nicht-persönlicher Kommunikation sprechen.

Answer (score 0):

**Brieffreund?**

Ich würde eventuell noch immer den klassischen Begriff Brieffreund benutzen, sofern ich überwiegend per Brief, E-Mail oder Text-Chats kommuniziere. Dass man ab und zu telefonisch Kontakt hat oder sich sogar physisch begegnet ist, ändert nichts an der Natur der Beziehung.

Der Begriff passt nicht perfekt und ist altmodisch, aber zumindest ist er kompakt.

Answer (score 0):

Vielleicht war die Antwort auf deine Frage heute im DLF zu hören. Da fragte jemand: "Verflacht eine Freundschaft, wenn man sie **hauptsächlich digital** pflegt?" Das schließt sämtliche "digital kommunizierte[n] Texte" ein, die du oben genannt hast, aber einige Telefonate und ein einziges Treffen nicht aus.

Wenn du den Beitrag hören möchtest: *"Like you! Freundschaft digital und analog"* in *Corso - Kunst und Pop*; 25.10. ab 15.05 h
https://srv.deutschlandradio.de/themes/streamplayer/index.html

Was das plötzliche Schweigen / Ignorieren betrifft, von dem du berichtet hast: Ich denke, dass es wenig mit den **Kommunikationsarten,-kanälen, -wegen** zu tun hat, sehr viel jedoch mit mangelnder sozialer Kompetenz und der Art der 'Beziehung' zwischen den beiden.

Cheers!